# Is zero vector always in a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

From Axler's LADR (paraphrased for simplicity), the following set is a subspace $U$ over $F^2$ if and only if $b=0$:
$$\{ (x_{1},x_{2}) : x_{1} = 5x_{2}+b\}$$
Why can't $b$ vary? An answer I read is this is because if you set $x_{1}$ to $0$ then $x_{2}$ would be $\frac{-b}{5} \neq 0$ which "shows" you can't get the zero vector and so $U$ isn't a subspace. And of course if $x_{2}$ to $0$ then $x_{1}$ is $b$, which isn't the zero vector. The reason for quotations is because can't you simply just multiply the entire list by $0$, which makes every component $0$ and thus get the $0$ vector?
As this subspace is closed under multiplication:
$$0\{5x_{2}+b,x_{2}\} = \{0,0\}$$ which is the zero vector

Comment: Not following.  The set of points $(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_1=5x_2+b$ does not contain $(0,0)$ unless $b=0$.  Indeed, if $x_2=0$ then $x_1=b$.  $b$ is fixed as a matter of the definition of the set.

Comment: By multiplying by $0$, you're imagining what would happen if $U = \{(x_1, x_2) : x_1 = 5x_2 + b\}$ were in fact a subspace. There's a name for this in linear algebra: the subspace generated by $U$. It can be denoted $\langle U \rangle$ and is precisely the smallest subspace which contains $U$. But note that for a subspace to contain $U$, it must contain things not in $U$, like, as you have noted, $0$.

Comment: Not an answer, but it might help your intuition. What does that straight line look line in the real two dimensional plane? When does it go through the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple reason - to answer the question in the title - is by definition. A vector subspace is still a vector space, and hence must contain a zero vector.

---

Now, yes, a vector space must be closed under multiplication as well. (That is, for $c \in F$ and $v \in V$ a vector space over $F$, we need $cv \in F$ for all $c,v$.)

So, sure, $0v$, i.e. the zero vector, needs to be in the vector space as well. But that's what the argument shows: that both $x_1,x_2$ cannot be zero at the same time unless $b = 0$.

If the zero vector, $(x_1,x_2) := (0,0)$, is in $U$, then $x_2 = 5x_1 + b$. But since $x_1=x_2=0$, then $0 = 5 \cdot 0 + b$, i.e. $0 = b$.

In other words, it is not a **given** that the zero vector is in $U$; you need to **prove** it is in $U$, in order to prove it is a subspace. This is a case where, even though $0 \in F$ and $v \in U$, that $0v = 0 \not \in U$. Hence it is not a subspace.

Comment: But even if I multiply the entire list by 0, regardless of what b is, doesn't everything still go to 0? Wouldn't that be a proof U is a subspace after 0v + 0b = 0?

Comment: Are you trying to multiply the vector by zero, or the equation by zero? If all vectors in the set satisfy $x_1 = 5x_2+b$, and if the set of vectors was closed under multiplication, then you could multiply a ***vector*** by zero and it would still satisfy the same equation $x_1 = 5x_2+b$. You do not multiply the equation by zero. Indeed, this is a way to show that $b=0$.

Comment: @Joe if I do multiply the vector by zero I get the zero vector, but it doesn't satisfy the same equation. The $x_{1}$ constraint seems to be nullified when I multiply by zero. I just feel like anything is a subspace since whenever I multiply it by zero the vector is now a zero vector!

Comment: I think you're having trouble understanding what the "it" is that you're multiplying. The set of vectors given by the equation $\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1=3\}$ is not a subspace because it does not contain $(0,0)$. It does contain $(3,0)$. If you multiply $(3,0)$ by $0$ you do get $(0,0)$, ***BUT*** that doesn't make $(0,0)$ in the set. It isn't in the set, as can be seen by the definition of the set. This means that the set is ***not*** closed under multiplication. If you multiply a vector from the set by $0$, you do not get a vector in the set.